# multiply record my maturity

Tags: sql, ms-access

Input:

I have 4 columns in a table:

```
KONTO   CUSTOMER_NUMBER   COLLATERAL_TYPE   MATURITY
```

`Konto` is unique value, maturity is value I need to multiply.

Example:

```
KONTO  CUSTOMER_NUMBER  COLLATERAL_TYPE  MATURITY
--------------------------------------------------
1           000234           H              4
2           000234           G              3
3           212567           H              5
```

I need to create table with every `KONTO` multiplied my max maturity and collateral type per customer. Maybe its easier to say, each collateral should have record fer every year of maturity

Output:

```
KONTO  CUSTOMER_NUMBER  COLLATERAL_TYPE  MATURITY
-------------------------------------------------
1           000234           H              1
1           000234           H              2
1           000234           H              3
1           000234           H              4
2           000234           G              1
2           000234           G              2
2           000234           G              3
3           212567           H              1
3           212567           H              2
3           212567           H              3
3           212567           H              4
3           212567           H              5
```

My colleagues from other firm managed to do it but I don't know how.

I use MS Access/SQL in MS Access.

Thank you and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    KontoTable.Konto, 
    KontoTable.Customer_Number, 
    KontoTable.Collateral_Type, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Maturity
FROM 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca, 
    KontoTable
WHERE 
    ((10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)) 
    Between 1 And KontoTable.Maturity);
```

Comment: this actually worked fine with me! :) I will try it tomorrow on my original database. I hope it will work. I will let you know! thank you!!!!

Comment: That's some creative usage of `MSysObjects`! Guess this won't work if `MSysObjects` is either missing a large sections of IDs or containing few IDs and many different maturities are needed, as far as I understand, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: _MSysObjects_ is never missing, but will hold a variety of IDs. However, the use of _Distinct_, _Abs_, and _Mod 10_ ensures that the IDs from 0 to 9 always will be present. If you prefer, you can replace with a simple "Numbers" table holding values from 0 to whatever.

Comment: @Gustav just didn't know that that worked independent of if the database actually has any non-system objects inside it. I know it always exists, just didn't expect that to work on an empty database (which it does). Great stuff, will help me avoid making tables with just numbers.

Comment: I have one more problem, shoud I open new question or ask here? Its conneceted with this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is really painful in MS Access, which doesn't have CTEs or window functions.  One method is:

```
select KONTO, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, COLLATERAL_TYPE, 1 as MATURITY
from t
where MATURITY >= 1
union all
select KONTO, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, COLLATERAL_TYPE, 2 as MATURITY
from t
where MATURITY >= 2
union all
select KONTO, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, COLLATERAL_TYPE, 3 as MATURITY
from t
where MATURITY >= 3
union all
select KONTO, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, COLLATERAL_TYPE, 4 as MATURITY
from t
where MATURITY >= 4
union all
select KONTO, CUSTOMER_NUMBER, COLLATERAL_TYPE, 5 as MATURITY
from t
where MATURITY >= 5;
```

Of course, you will  have to repeat this pattern up to your maximum maturity.

Comment: Ok, thank you. My collaterals dont have more than 30 years maturity but I have 10 types od collateral and more than 30000 customers. What do you mean by "doesn't have CTEs or window functions"?

Comment: @Dropbox13 . . . Using this method, you will need 30 subqueries.  CTEs and window functions are standard features in SQL that MS Access does not support.

Comment: I have one more problem, shoud I open new question or ask here? Its conneceted with this question.

Comment: @Dropbox13 . . . You should ask a new question.  Changing an existing question after it has answers is rude.  It can invalidate answers which in turn can encourage downvotes.